# Check if coordinate is inside screen rectangle

Tags: javascript, geolocation, coordinates, geospatial

I have an array containing around half a million objects which each look like this:

```
{
    "a": "50.400343" // latitude coordinate
    "b": "-1.434934" // longitude coordinate
    "c": "fr234NFDD"  // reference to talk to API
}
```

I need to create a function that loops through every one of these objects and checks if they're inside the screen's coordinates. A visual example:

[image]

I need to show the coordinates on the map in < 1 second so it needs to be efficient (remembering that this function will be performing operations around 500,000 times).

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think its possible to have half a million items in memory and then loop through them and give the response back to user in < 1 sec if you are coding for browser.

Comment: @sabithpocker If that's the case should I split up the arrays into smaller ones? It's for mobile so even worse lol

Comment: yes, you will have to find an alternate way probably, but start wil some performance tests comparing say `iterating` vs `map`

Comment: you can edit this to use your actual objects http://jsperf.com/arraymap and be sure to check in actual devices you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I removed the console.logs (time consuming) and it spins pretty quickly. I added a quick timer.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/fsY72/6/)

```
function find(rect, list) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < half_a_million.length; i++) {
        if (half_a_million[i].a >= rect.x1 && half_a_million[i].a <= rect.x2 && half_a_million[i].b >= rect.y1 && half_a_million[i].b <= rect.y2) {
            console.log(half_a_million[i].c + ' is a solution.');
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    console.log('All solutions found: ' + count);
}
```